# Simple string and Integer pipe not working inside template helper

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have this code inside a template (`html.eex` file):

```
<%= @width |> String.replace("px", "") |> Integer.parse |> (*0.8) %>
```

where `@width` is `"125px"`.

I'm getting two errors:

1) protocol Phoenix.HTML.Safe not implemented for {125, ""};

2) syntax error before: '*'

Does this mean that it's not possible to use pipes like this inside a template helper or that I'm not writing it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

First of all the end of your pipeline isn't a call to a function:

```
iex> 125 |> (*0.8)
** (SyntaxError) iex:6: syntax error before: '*'
```

What you want is:

```
iex> 125 |> Kernel.*(0.8)
100.0
```

Second of all, [Integer.parse/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/Integer.html#parse/2) returns a tuple:

```
iex> Integer.parse("125")
{125, ""}
```

You can use [String.to_integer/1](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/String.html#to_integer/1) instead:

```
iex> String.to_integer("125")
125
```

Resulting in:

```
<%= @width |> String.replace("px", "") |> String.to_integer() |> Kernel.*(0.8) %>
```

If you use Integer.parse then you don't need the String.replace but you do need to fetch the element from the tuple:

```
<%= @width |> Integer.parse() |> elem(0) |> Kernel.*(0.8) %>
```